# Crontab permission denied despite user being listed in /etc/cron.allow

Tags: cron

I'm attempting to run crontab as the "ubuntu" user on a machine running Ubuntu 20.04. I get a permission denied error despite the "ubuntu" user existing in `/etc/cron.allow`.

```
$ crontab -l
/etc/cron.allow: Permission denied
You (ubuntu) are not allowed to use this program (crontab)
See crontab(1) for more information
```

I have older machines running on Ubuntu 18.04 with the same `/etc/cron.allow` configuration where running crontab succeeds. Only when testing on 20.04 do I get permission denied.

Also worth noting that file permissions for `/etc/cron.allow` are set to 600. If I manually set the permissions to 644, then I can successfully run crontab as `ubuntu`, but I would like to keep the 600 setting if possible. On the 18.04 machines, the permissions are 600 and crontab still succeeds.

Comment: Perhaps you could compromise and make it 640 with ownership `root:crontab`?

Comment: ... fyi the 18.04 behavior appears to have been [a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cron/+bug/1813833) that has since been fixed

Answer (score 0):

Credit to [@steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver)

> ... fyi the 18.04 behavior appears to have been a bug that has since been fixed

Their suggested fix of setting the file permissions of `/etc/cron.allow` to 640 and setting ownership to `root:crontab` solved my issue.